# JPA 2.0 @ManyToMany relationship using hibernate 5.X

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-5.x

I'm having some troubles trying to save on database entities using JPA with Hibernate 5.X.

I have two entities already persisted on database and a method to create a relationship between them. The relationship is not created when calling the method on a stateless session bean. Some code bellow to help understand.

Alan

Entity Person.class:

```
/* imports needed */

@Entity

public class Person implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons")
  private Set<Project> projects;

  /* default contructor, getters and setters. No equals and hashcode implemented */

}
```

Entity Project.class

```
/* imports needed */

@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Person> persons;

  /* default contructor, getters and setters. No equals and hashcode implemented */

}
```

Stateless session bean Bean.class

```
/* imports needed */

@Stateless
public class Bean {

  @Inject
  private EntityManager em;

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public Person findPersonById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Person.class, id);
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public Project findProjectById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Project.class, id);
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void attachProjectToPerson(Project project, Person person) {
    project.getPersons().add(person);
    person.getProjects().add(project);
    em.merge(project);
  }
}
```

Relevant hibernate properties on Persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primary">
    ...
    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer" value="true" />
      ...
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Sample code using bean and classes

```
...
// User and Project with id Long(1) already exists on database
Person person = bean.findPersonById(1L); //Person retrieved right
Project project = bean.findProjectById(1L); //Project retrieved right

// When called nothing happens on table PROJECT_PERSON
bean.attachProjectToPerson(project, person);
...
```

Comment: Try adding `em.merge(person);` along with `em.merge(project);`

Comment: Trying your suggestion @PredragMaric not worked. I replaced full method `attachProjectToPerson` with:  
`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)  
 public void attachProjectToPerson(Project project, Person person) {  
  project = em.merge(project);  
  person = em.merge(person);  
  project.getPersons().add(person);  
  person.getProjects().add(project);  
 }`. Disabling hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer it worked. Anyone knows if it is a bug? I need use it because I have some properties with @Basic annotation with lazy properties

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using @JoinTable in Project.class..It should fix your problem.A join table is necessary to facilitate the many-to-many relationship.I think this may be one issue.

Comment: `@JoinTable` is not necessary, there is a default one used if the annotation is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to call `em.persist(project)`, not `em.merge(project)`. You will also need to call `em.persist(person)` unless you change the `cascade` value on `Project.person`'s `@ManyToMany` mapping.

The `merge(...)` method is for merging a "detached" entity back into the entity manager's persistence context.